# Rails Route for Adding child to parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Been working in another language for a few months and trying to get back into Rails.

If I have a model `House`, and a model `Door`, so that `Door` `belongs_to` `House` and `House` has_many `Doors`.

If I want to add a `door` to the `house`, do I use the route:

```
add_door_path
```

or is it

```
add_door_path(@house)
```

And if so how do I embed the `house_id` in to it?  Or do I need to create a new route for that?  Is it part of the standard `resources` or is this entirely custom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have

```
# routes.rb
resources :house do
  resources :doors
end
```

then you would have `house_doors_path(@house)`

That is because in your routes you have specified that doors is nested inside the house. You would need the parameter inside because the path requires a house id.

To check for the routes, go here `http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes`.

If on the other hand, if you have

```
# routes.rb
post '/door/' => 'doors#create', as: :add_door
```

the new door would not know which house it belongs to. so you can add
`post '/house/:id/door ...` which you also need a parameter of house so your syntax would be `add_door_path(@house)`

I hope that answers your question.